# Ubuntu, Installing opencv-contrib by pip command, but some algorithms are still not working

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I use the following command to install opencv:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

But for some algorithms, such as `SIFT`, `KNearest`, it still gives me an error :

```
module `cv2.cv2` has no attribute `KNearest`
```

Does that mean the unique way to solve it is using cmake to install `opencv` and `opencv-contrib`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two algorithms that you have mentioned they are moved to different modules.

`SIFT` : can be accessed using `sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()`

`KNearest` : can be accessed using `knn = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()`

so you may have to check once whether the module is shifted to another place.